# Pythonic way to "default" a conditional statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

I have an if-elif-else structure with multiple levels, but the last-level `else` is always the same statement:

```
if statement1:
    if something:
        do_thing()
    elif something_else:
        if something_something:
            do_thing_something()
        elif somethingg:
            do_thingg()
        else:
            do_default()
    else:
        do_default()
else: 
    do_default()
```

As you can see, I use `do_default()` 3 times, and I feel like there's a better way. This would basically be a `default` in a `switch-case` statement in other languages, but Python does not have `switch-case`. I was wondering if there's any other way I could solve this more elegantly/"Pythonically"? [Or is the only way to use dicts or implement my own `switch-case`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)?

Comment: Are you seeking a general solution or just for your particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pack it into a function and write it as in

```py
def wrapper(args):
    if statement1:
        if something:
            return do_thing()
        elif something_else:
            if something_something:
                return do_thing_something()
           elif somethingg:
                return do_thingg()
    do_default()
```

Though you do have to write return multiple times

Answer (score 5):

You could try un-nesting your conditionals:

```
if statement1 and something:
    do_thing()
elif statement1 and something_else and something_something:
    do_thing()
elif statement1 and something_else and somethingg:
    do_thingg()
else:
    do_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling this block into a function may help:

```
def do_things():
    if statement1:
        if something:
            return do_thing()
        elif something_else:
            if something_something:
                return do_thing_something()
            elif somethingg:
                return do_thingg()
    return do_default()
```